# C program Solaris to AIX Migration

Tags: c, gcc, aix

I've a C program that has the below inbuilt functions

strrspn

strfind

sqlcxt

But when I compile the same program in AIX using gcc compiler, it throws the below errors.

ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .strrspn

ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .strfind

ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .sqlcxt

Please advise how to resolve these errors. Is there any other functions with functionality as the above functions in AIX server?

Comment: You may get answers from people who know AIX (but not Solaris) if you add a short description what these functions do.

Comment: These are extensions (I think from BSD), you will have to write your own versions.  Just Google them, there are a number of places you can get the source code from.  Read the licence comments carefully.  This is the price for going outside the C standards.

Comment: @cdarke `sqlcxt` sounds lik Oracle rather than BSD, I reckon, but searching the net should indeed help; it should be somewhere like `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`, where `$ORACLE_HOME` ought to be set to the Oracle installation. I take it you (Vinoth) know about the options `ld -L -l` to direct the library search.